# Is it risky to convert Float to Double in my asp.net mvc application

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I have created a `MedicalLabResult` table on **Sql server 2008** that have a `Result` field with datatype of `Float`.

but when i have mapped my database using Entity Framework , the DBContext template automatically assign a `Double` data type to my `Result` field on the model class.
so if i try to write something as:-

```
float result = MedicalLabResult.Single().Result;
```

Then visual studio will raise an error `that it can not implicitly convert float to double` ,so i had to modify the above to :-

```
double result = MedicalLabResult.Single().Result;
```

But since the datatype for the `Result` field in the database is `Float`,, **so will it be risky to converte `Float` to `Double` in regards to losing any data?**
BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity framework designer did everything right. Sql server `Float` datatype is actually 64 bit double precision floating point number, its equivalent in CLR is `System.Double`. If you want to store single precision floating point then you have to use `real` in sql. It is mapped to CLR `System.Single`.

For further references of SQL Server and CLR datatypes you can go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx)